# Dynamic Data Site doesn't filter by nchar field

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have 2 tables that have a foreign-key relationship through the field that has nchar type.

Database designer successfully created relationship and displays it on database diagram. But  entity model created doesn't have this relationship, and as a result dynamic data site doesn't allow automated filtering by that parameter.

Is it possible to force that relationship be mapped to entity data model?

If no, how to apply filter on that field?

Answer (score 0):

Dav Check if your foreign table have primary key or not. I faced same problem but after adding primary key to foreign it got resolved. Please try once.

If still you are facing problem you can use FilterUIHint annotation to do it.